# Separable polynomial with splitting field an unramified extension?

Tags: number-theory, field-theory, ramification

I am trying to prove a theorem and it seems that I need that an irreducible polynomial $f(x)$ that is separable over $\mathfrak{p}$ has its splitting field an unramified extension of $\mathbb{Q}_\mathfrak{p}$, the original field.

Is this true? And if so, any hints on how to approach it?

Comment: Is $\mathfrak p$ a prime of $\mathbb{Z}$?  Let's say $\mathfrak p = p\mathbb{Z}$ for a prime number $p$.  What do you mean by "$f$ is separable over $p$?"  Do you mean that the reduction of $f$ modulo $p$ is separable polynomial $\mathbb{F}_p[X]$?  This is always the case, because $\mathbb{F}_p$ is perfect.

Comment: or do you mean when you factor $f$ modulo $p$, it is squarefree?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are asking is how to prove the following:

> Let $f \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$ be a monic irreducible polynomial.  Let $L$ be the splitting field of $f$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.  If the reduction of $f$ modulo $p$ is squarefree, then $L/\mathbb{Q}$ is unramified at $p$.

If $\mathbb{Q} \subseteq K \subseteq L$ are fields, $p$ a rational prime, then $L$ unramified at $p$ implies $K$ is unramified in $p$.  On the other hand, a compositum of unramified extensions at a given prime remains unramified.  So your question is equivalent to asking the following question:

> Let $f \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$ be a monic irreducible polynomial.  Let $\alpha$ be any root of $f$, and let $K = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$.  If the reduction of $f$ modulo $p$ is squarefree, then $K/\mathbb{Q}$ is unramified at $p$.

**Lemma**: let $F$ be a perfect field, let $g \in F[X]$ be monic and irreducible.  If $\alpha_1, ... , \alpha_t$ are all the roots of $g$, counting multiplicity, in some algebraic closure of $F$, then the discriminant $\textrm{disc}(g)$ of $g$, is the element $$\prod\limits_{i\neq j} (\alpha_i - \alpha_j)$$
It lies in $F$ and does not depend on the choice of algebraic closure.  In fact, it is a polynomial function of the coefficients of $g$.  The polynomial $g$ has a repeated root if and only if $g$ is squarefree as a product of irreducibles, if and only if the discriminant of $F$ is zero.

Now let $d$ be the discriminant of $f$.  There is a notion of a *discriminant of a number field*, denoted $\delta = \delta(K/\mathbb{Q})$.  It is an integer, well defined up to sign.  **The important result is that $K$ is unramified at a given prime number $q$ if and only if $q$ divides $\delta$.**

Now, since $f$ is monic, $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha] \subseteq \mathcal O_K$, the ring of integers of $K$.  To these two rings we may associate integers, which we call their discriminants.  As a result of that subset inclusion, one can show the the discriminant of $\mathcal O_K$ (which turns out to be $\delta$) divides the discriminant of $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ (which turns out to be $d = \textrm{disc } f$).

We claim that $K$ is unramified at $p$. If not, then $p$ divides $d$, whence the reduction of $d$ modulo $p$ is zero.  But one can show that the reduction of $d$ modulo $p$ is exactly the discriminant of the reduction of $f$ modulo $p$.  Thus $\overline{f} \in \mathbb{F}_p[X]$ is not squarefree, contradiction.

Comment: Thank you. Though I am wondering--what if $\mathfrak{p}$ is prime ideal in the splitting field? Does the same still apply?

Comment: What property do you want $f$ to have with respect to $\mathfrak p$?

Comment: $\mathfrak{p}|p$ with $f$ reduction modulo $p$ is squarefree.

Comment: What do you mean?  If $\mathfrak p$ is a prime lying over $p$, what does $\mathfrak p$ have to do with the factorization of $f$ modulo $p$?

Comment: Oh. I was confused. It makes sense now.